# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in WAMP 2.5

Tags: php, oracle, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I have installed OCI Client Version  instantclient-basiclite-nt-11.2.0.4.0.zip and add its path in environment variable. Enable extension in php.ini file as well. In phpinfo it gives OCI8 is available but when i try to connect it with database it started giving me error. Tried with 32/64 bit client libraries but nothing is working.

I have windows 7 64 bit and using WAMP 2.5 version.

I will be really thankful if anybody can guide me where i am wrong and what I should do to overcome this problem.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() this is the error i am getting when i tried to connect to the db. before this I do not get any error

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit

Comment: 64 bit WAMP Server is installed on my machine.